# MYSQL Query: extract all records that have SSCF in the LicenseNumber

Tags: syntax, mysql

I need to get a SQL Query that I can execute to extract certain data.  Here are the details:

- DB Type: MySQL
- DB Name: adminDB
- Table Name: licenseinfo
- Field Name: LicenseNumber

So the data in the LicenseNumber Column looks like this: ( this is just a sample there are 300,000 Records)

---

SSCY-334-0W2-5AA

SSCY-238-2W1-5F9

SSCY-378-0W5-5BD

SSCY-312-061-5PO

SSCF-323-0R2-5FW

SSCF-548-2U1-5OL

SSCF-332-0G5-5BY

SSCF-398-041-5PE

---

I need to extract all records that have SSCF in the LicenseNumber

I tried query builder in SQLYog but I was getting syntax errors.

Can Someone please write this query for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the letters are always at the start:

```
SELECT * FROM licenseinfo WHERE LicenseNumber LIKE 'SSCF%'
```

If you really do mean that the text 'SSCF' can be anywhere in the license number you can use LIKE '%SSCF%' instead, but if your sample data is representative, I think this will return the same results but be slower.

Comment: If there is an index on LicenseNumber the fixed at the front version will use the key.  Otherwise you'll get no help from the index.

Comment: @Epsilon Prime: +1 good point. This could make the speed difference quite large.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work:

```
select * from licenseinfo where LicenseNumber like 'SSCF%'
```